# Prototype UITableViewCell accessory covers up subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, accessory

I would like to use the provided disclosure indicator accessory in my prototype cell.  However, enabling it covers up the right hand portion of my custom cell divider.  (Since my divider does not span the full width of the cell, I do not want to use the built in divider).

Is there a way I can use the built in cell accessories, while still utilizing the full width of my cell's view?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is resize your divider, based on the location of the accessory view.

You can override layoutSubviews, like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect accessoryFrame = self.accessoryView.frame;
    CGRect yourCustomViewFrame = yourCustomView.frame;
    yourCustomViewFrame.size.width = accessoryFrame.origin.x - yourCustomViewFrame.origin.x;
    [yourCustomView setFrame:yourCustomViewFrame];
}
```

Comment: HaiR, I tried this out, but subclassing the cells appeared to mess up the tableview.  I tried the same basic concept in willDisplayCell, but with no luck.  Apologies for the title, it should have said static cells, not prototype.  I ended up just removing the custom dividers, since I was able to do so on that view.